# How to generate List in a clearer way?

Tags: java, list

I have the following list of elements (Call it `lst`), for instance:

```
[1, 2, 2, 5, 78, 768, 6823, 43, 234]
```

I need to create the `List<Container>` where

```
public class Container{

   private int value;
   private List<Integer> children;

   public Container(int i){ //impl
   }

   //other staff
}
```

as follows:

`Container(1)` has no children, therefore its children filed = `null`.

Both `Container(2)` are the same and has one child `Container(1)`.

`Container(5)` has two children `Container(2)` and One more `Container(2)`.

`Container(43)` has one child `Container(5)`.

and so forth.

So, I could write `if-else` condition as follows:

```
List<Integer> lst; //the list of the integers
List<Integer> leastElems = new ArrayList<Integer>();

Integer leastElem = Collections.min(lst);

for(Integer e : lst){
        if(e.equals(leastElem))
            leastElems.add(e);
}

List<Integer> withourLeastElems = new ArrayList<>(lst);
withourLeastElems.removeAll(leastElems) ;
Collections.sort(withourLeastElems);

List<Container> containers = new ArrayList<>();
//filling the containers according to the requirements;
```

The code looks extremely wierd. So I'd like to ask you advice of how to do it better?

Comment: I didn't understand the logic of what defines a container and its children. Why does `Container(43)` have a child `Container(5)`?

Comment: Maybe it looks extremely weird because your requirements are extremely weird? :-)

Comment: @Kayaman because the preceding of the 43 is 5.

Comment: So, for each number in the list, you want to create a container, and this container should have the previous number as a child, as many times as the child number is in the list? Is that the rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```
List<Integer> lst; //the list of the integers
lst.removeAll(Collections.singleton(Collections.min(lst)));

Collections.sort(lst);

List<Container> containers = new ArrayList<>();
//filling the containers according to the requirements;
```

Since you only use the leastElem-List to remove all elements, which are equal to leastElem you need only to remove all leastElem from the list and the result will be the same.